# heroku hosted flask app redirects to localhost

Tags: python, heroku, flask, localhost

i currently have a flask app hosted on Horoku. When i visit the page it opens just as it should (renders a html page). However whenever i perform an action that redirects the user (e.g. submit a form) to another directory of the app it tries to redirect to local host and fails (it works if i manually change the url in the url bar). I feel like there's a very simple fix to this but nothing i do seems to make a difference. here's an example...

```
@app.route('/')
def message_page():
    return(render_template('message_page.html')) 

@app.route('/message_receiver', methods = ['POST'])
def message_reciever():
    message  = request.form['msg']

    ***some other stuff***

    return(redirect(url_for('message_page')))
```

i tried specifying the host as 0.0.0.0 in both the app.route() parts and the app.run() at the bottom of the app but that made no difference. Note: this works perfectly well when running on localhost (i suppose it masks the problem). I figure the problem must be to do with the url_for() function but i dont know how to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have experience with flask, but [docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/) say that you can pass `_external=True` to `url_for` method. This will generate absolute url and you can control actual host with `SERVER_NAME` environment variable. So you should it set it up on heroku:

```
heroku config:set SERVER_NAME=your_host
```

Comment: thank you for your effort but it did not work for me. It still redirects to local host

Answer (score 0):

Well, according to the [help page](https://help.heroku.com/XK5Z8F62/when-i-access-my-custom-domain-i-m-redirected-another-url), Heroku doesn't redirect. So any redirects are performed by your app.